# Coping floating bar chart data online

Tags: javascript, css, charts, tooltip, element

I am trying to copy data on a floating column/line chart online.

I just can not seem to find away to copy the details. See image below.

[image]

In inspect, I came across the codes that I believe can help me show the data.

These are the codes:

```html
<div class="highcharts-tooltip" style="position: absolute; left: 815px; top: -9999px; visibility: visible;"><span style="position: absolute; font-family: &quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; white-space: nowrap; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; left: 8px; top: 8px;"
    zindex="1"><span style="text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; display: table !important;">Sep 2018</span><span class="hawk-tt" style="display: block; color:#185AA9;"> 325</span></span>
</div>


<span style="position: absolute; font-family: &quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; white-space: nowrap; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; left: 8px; top: 8px;"
  zindex="1"><span style="text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; display: table !important;">Jan 2018</span><span class="hawk-tt" style="display: block; color:#185AA9;"> -892</span></span>


<span style="text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; display: table !important;">Jul 2018</span>


<span class="hawk-tt" style="display: block; color:#185AA9;"> 1.18K</span>
```

Comment: will you please tell in which format you want to display  the data ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I really appreciate your response. "please tell in which format you want to display the data" As a plain text. Separating Dates from values to copy to a spread sheet.

Comment: PRADIP GORULE. How do you want me to proceed?